# What are the recent (newest) FK, IK solvers?

Tags: ros, kinematics, kdl, inverse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, colleagues!

Please advise me, what is the newest ROS packages for solving forward and inverse robot arm kinematics. Several years ago I tested OROCOS KDL.  Is it actual in using with Noetic?

Particularly, at this moment I'm looking for inverse jacobian velocity control (cartesian velocity back to joints velocities).
What me to look for?

Best wishes!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369154/what-are-the-recent-(newest)-fk,-ik-solvers?/) by [MaximN74](https://answers.ros.org/users/37023/maximn74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2021-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-09**:\

> Particularly, at this moment I'm looking for inverse jacobian velocity control (cartesian velocity back to joints velocities).

wouldn't that be inverse dynamics instead?

**Comment by [MaximN74](https://answers.ros.org/users/37023/maximn74/) on 2021-01-10**:
Generally, yes. But at this moment kinematics is enough.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-10**:
Well it's a rather different bit of functionality. There are quite a few IK solvers with plugins for MoveIt fi, but far less inverse dynamics solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> inverse jacobian velocity control (cartesian velocity back to joints velocities)

Inverse Jacobian velocity control is the exact description for [moveit_servo](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/master/moveit_ros/moveit_servo), so you should check that out! If you already have your robot set up with MoveIt, this should be pretty easy to use (also you might already have it installed via `apt`)

---

Originally posted by [APettinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/41977/apettinger/) with karma: 118 on 2021-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-11**:\

> If you already have your robot set up with MoveIt, this should be pretty easy to use

if you have a driver capable of providing the kind of high bandwidth, low jitter interface servo needs.

**Comment by [MaximN74](https://answers.ros.org/users/37023/maximn74/) on 2021-01-11**:
Thanks, colleagues. Will try.